# Remove address from sequence in HD wallet

Tags: blockchain, address, privacy, bip32-hd-wallets

Is there a way to eject an address out of the sequence of an HD wallet?

Lets say an address was used for a political donation to a regime in Namibia that may get international condemnation a few decades in the future (can never tell with political parties, maybe they don't invade Russia in the winter and end up writing the history books) or perhaps anyone that donated to a campaign against zombie equality rights is now condemned publicly in the unforeseen future even after the majority population donated and voted the same way you did

Therefore I don't want that to appear in my wallet, whether I restore a seed on a different device or future wallet. But I only thought of this after the address was used. This is considering the possibility that in some future, I may accidentally mix inputs to other addresses, providing for blockchain analysis of addresses I own, or perhaps I simply leave my computer unlocked at some point in the future and someone is able to see my addresses.

Is there a way to eject that address from the HD sequence or perhaps is this simply a GUI thing that software clients would have to do on there own?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with dropping an address from an HD wallet is that they are deterministic, so how do you change the determined sequence? The only way I see is creating a new HD wallet (a new sequence), transfer all your money there, and then denying the original affected one was yours (this may need coin mixing).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to 'drop address' from an HD sequence. You could sweep your funds(mix them) and move them into a (cleaner)different HD wallet if you're worried being able to getting linked to that address.